# wpf master detail listviews binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I have three viewmodels:
AccountListViewModel(has a collection of accountviewmodels and a selectedaccount property)

```
public ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> AccountList 
public AccountViewModel SelectedAccount
```

AccountViewModel(has a collection of transactionviewmodel)

```
public ObservableCollection<TransactionViewModel> Transactions
```

and a TransactionViewModel.

I set the datacontext of the mainwindow to the AccountListViewModel and I have two Usercontrols(AccountListView and TransactionListView) that I set in the mainwindow as content control.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AccountListTemplate" >
        <views:AccountListView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="TransactionListTemplate" >
        <views:TransactionListView />
</DataTemplate>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate=" {StaticResource AccountListTemplate}" />
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedAccount}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TransactionListTemplate}" />
```

This is the itemssource of the AccountListView usercontrol

```
<ListView x:Name="AccountList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedAccounts}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount}" >
```

and the itemssource for the TransactionListView usercontrol

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}" >
```

The AccountList is displaying correctly but when I select an account no transactions are displayed although the logic is correct I think.

The Content property of the contentcontrol that holds the TransactionListView is set to SelectedAccount and the TransactionListView itemsource is the Transactions collection so whenever i click an account the transactions collection of that account should be displayed in the second contentcontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem and see if that works. You may also have to change your mode to two-way and update your source trigger.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Selected}"
              Margin="10">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Test Checked" Binding="{Binding S}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is an example of a data grid, but the same concepts apply.

Comment: It seems like you are losing something with having so many view models. Why not just have classes to hold your transactions and account data and have your main view model do the binding to access your back-end classes?

Comment: I think I understand your situation more. I also tried to create a test app to replicate the situation and I was unable to get the transaction listview to update. I did it a little differently, but same problem. I saw the selected value raised event, but could not trigger the transaction update. I may have to look further into this. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Ye, its like Transactions is not binding even through the Selected event is raised.